# Can not ssh-add private key to docker build

Tags: git, docker, ssh, ssh-agent

I'm trying to add a local private key to the ssh-agent (docker image) during the build process.

**Problem**
I've run  `eval$(ssh-agent -s)` and once docker runs the `ssh-add /etc/ssh/id_rsa` I receive the following error:

`Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.`

**Goal**:
I need to clone a private git repo during to NPM install process. This local key will allow me to authenticate against the private repo.

==== Output Snippet ====

```
Step 8/16 : RUN eval $(ssh-agent -s)
 ---> Running in 195ffeb1f84f
Agent pid 8
 ---> 0fcbc89d362f
Removing intermediate container 195ffeb1f84f
Step 9/16 : RUN ssh-add /etc/ssh/id_rsa
 ---> Running in ae99039e1fba
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
The command '/bin/sh -c ssh-add /etc/ssh/id_rsa' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Comment: The agent you run in Step 8 is dead by the time you are in Step 9. You need or perform all steps in one go for this to work. `RUN eval $(ssh-agent -s) && ssh-add /etc/ssh/id_rsa && git checkout .....`

Comment: I literally just figured this out. thanks so much!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The agent you run in Step 8 is dead by the time you are in Step 9. You need or perform all steps in one go for this to work.

```
RUN eval $(ssh-agent -s) && ssh-add /etc/ssh/id_rsa && git checkout .....
```

Comment: This was the exact code I used in my dockerfile.  I also moved from the Alpine image to Node: 9 (jessie)

`RUN echo "$ssh_prv_key" > /etc/ssh/id_rsa && echo "$ssh_pub_key" > /etc/ssh/id_rsa.pub && chmod 600 /etc/ssh/id_rsa && chmod 600 /etc/ssh/id_rsa.pub && \
    chmod 600 /etc/ssh/ && \
    eval $(ssh-agent -s) && \
    ssh-add /etc/ssh/id_rsa && \
    ssh-add -l && \
    cat /etc/ssh/id_rsa && cat /etc/ssh/id_rsa.pub && \
    npm install -g sails && \
    npm install `

Comment: Thank you! This saved me after a day of scratching my head and trying random things

Comment: OMG... yes, this works. I've been trying so many different ways to achieve this and it appears this approach (calling everything in one go) is truly the only way to make this work.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use volume in your container?

You can mount `/etc/ssh/id_rsa` in container volume with `/root/.ssh/id_rsa` path.

Comment: you can only utilize a mount volume during run time.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this has challenges with the ownership of `~/.ssh/config`. I haven't found a way around this yet.